# How can I open a external App from my React-Native App in IOS?

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native

I am trying to open for example, What'sApp from my own React-Native App. I have reach to do this in Android with react-native-send-intent (SendIntentAndroid) but it only works in Android. I would like to do the same in IOS. Linking does not work for me and I don't know why.

Comment: What happens if you use `Linking.openURL('whatsapp://');`? Do you get any console errors when using Linking?

Comment: I've tried and nothing happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, in IOS is Linking.openUR("whatsapp://app") The word APP was what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to share some thing from your app to other apps then you can do so by **`Share`** module of react native.
docs for this module is available [here](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.49/docs/share.html#share).

And is you want to open other apps like whatsapp,or gmail or mail app, etc. then you can do so by implementing an **[native-module](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.49/docs/native-modules-ios.html#native-modules)** in IOS as.

```
#import "RCTBridgeModule.h"

#ifndef SampleNativeModule_h
#define SampleNativeModule_h
#endif /* SampleNativeModule_h */

@interface SampleNativeModule_h : NSObject <RCTBridgeModule>

@end
```

the above file is **SampleNativeModule.h**

```
#import "SampleNativeModule.h"
#import "RCTLog.h"

@import UIKit;
@implementation SampleNativeModule


RCT_EXPORT_MODULE();

RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(openGmail)
{
  NSURL* mailURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"message://"];
  NSURL* gmailURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"googlegmail://"];
  NSURL* appStoreURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"itms://itunes.apple.com/us/app/googlegmail"];

  if([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:gmailURL]){
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:gmailURL];
  }else if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:mailURL]) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:mailURL];
  }else{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:appStoreURL];
  }
}

@end
```

the above file is SampleNativeModule.m

which is native module file and you can can this as

```
import {NativeModules} from 'react-native'
const SampleNativeModule = NativeModules.SampleNativeModule;
//    ........

SampleNativeModule.openGmail();
```

above i implemented method to open gmail app in IOS, but you can do for whatsapp and other app, by passing URL to your native module and open the corresponding app.

Comment: Thanks for comment. I have a doubt, I don't know where to create this file . I know nothing of Objetive C or swift. In the doc does not say where to create the file neither. Excuse my english.

Comment: You can create in IOS folder of your react-nativeproject.
And details info is available in the docs for native modules.

Comment: There’s no need for a custom native module here, the `Linking` API already offers `openURL` and `canOpenURL`: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking.html